# Db design help for Mobile device db in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database with 5 tables:

1. `device_company`
2. `device_series`
3. `device_model`
4. `device_type`
5. `device_data`

`device_data` will contain the `id` of all the above tables.

I am wondering whether this is the best way to store the data? Or, should I first create an entry in the fifth table and then store that id in tables 1-4. 
Which method will be more scalable as the no of devices continue to grow or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What's in each table?  Are the first four tables dimensions/lookup tables and the fifth collects them?

Comment: The first four tables contain information about the device like brand name, device name, type of device, device os etc

Comment: That doesn't really tell me any more than your original question.  Do the foreign keys point from the first four tables to the fifth, or the other way around?  Or is it vertical partitioning, with IDs shared across all the tables?  An example might be helpful; as it stands you're at risk of having your question closed as unclear.

Comment: Do the devices often have the same type or model, etc?  If not, a single table should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that the first four tables contain data that describes a specific device.

I'll make an assumption that `device_data` will identify a particular device (based on the info in the other tables), and that the ID of this table will be used in other tables to identify every specific device.

It's worth clarifying this point: There should be a single ID that uniquely identifies each device, and that's separate from (for example) device readings over time, or device repair/deployment history, or anything like that. If the `data` part of `device_data` isn't part of uniquely identifying a specific device, then some other table *should* match that description.

That said, then it makes more sense to have the various lookup table IDs as foreign keys in `device_data` than it does to push the `device_id` out to the other tables. For example, a `device_company` is presumably the manufacturer of multiple different series, model, and type of devices. If so, then for the `device_id` to exist in `device_company`, then multiple rows in the table would have the same company data. This would violate normalization rules.

The question I would have is, are the other four tables all completely independent? Would every device of a given series be from the same company? Would every model be from the same company, or part of the same series? What about type - is that independent of the other tables?

If the tables are not independent, then you wouldn't need all the IDs in `device_data`. If every series or model will come from a specific company, then the `device_company_id` should be in `device_series` and/or `device_model`; the `device_series_id` or the `device_model_id` would already specify the `device_company_id`. Similarly, if each model ties back to one and only one series, then `device_series_id` should be in `device_model`, and can be left out of `device_data` (because `device_model_id` essentially also specifies `device_series_id`).

In most cases, a simple normalized approach like this will be your best bet for storing the data. As a general rule of thumb, it's best to start with you data normalized, and only denormalize it if performance problems force you to. Denormalized data is much harder to maintain than normalized data.